Hyperlinks are not added in run mode but they are in debug mode
I'm running Excel version 2408. The following code populates two tables using a query connection and then adds some hyperlinks. The hyperlinks are added correctly for the first table (tblNoStop) but not for the second (tblNoOffice).
If I put a break before the loop that populates the hyperlinks for the second table and then hit F5 from the debugger, everything works fine.
I have tried adding the DoEvents instruction and forced a wait time of up to one minute, but no success.
I also tried commenting out the first loop, but the result is the same: hyperlinks in table tblNoOffice are only added in debug mode.
Does anybody have an idea?
Here is the relevant part of my code:
'For each liine of the tables update hyperlinks
For RowCounter = 1 To tblNoStop.ListRows.Count
    
    'Add link to the staff  details in the ADAM web application
    Set HLRange = tblNoStop.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOSTOP_INDEXCOLIND)
    Call AddHL(HLRange, _
        wsNoStop, _
        "https://adam.unctad.unctad.org/StaffDetails.aspx?id=" & tblNoStop.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOSTOP_INDEXCOLIND).Value & "&activemenu=1", _
        "", _
        SCRTIP & tblNoStop.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOSTOP_FIRSTNAMECOLIND).Text & " " & tblNoStop.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOSTOP_LASTNAMECOLIND) & ADAMWEB)

    'Add link to the staff requests' list in the ADAM web application
    Set HLRange = tblNoStop.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOSTOP_STOPACCCOLIND)
    Call AddHL(HLRange, _
        wsNoStop, _
        "https://adam.unctad.unctad.org/RequestList.aspx?id=" & tblNoStop.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOSTOP_INDEXCOLIND).Value & "&activemenu=1", _
        "", _
        SCRTIP & tblNoStop.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOSTOP_FIRSTNAMECOLIND).Text & " " & tblNoStop.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOSTOP_LASTNAMECOLIND) & ADAMREQ)
    
    'Add link to the staff's equipment assignment history
    Set HLRange = tblNoStop.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOSTOP_FIRSTNAMECOLIND)
    Call AddHL(HLRange, _
        wsNoStop, _
        "https://adam.unctad.unctad.org/itinventory/EquipmentAssignment.aspx?id=" & tblNoStop.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOSTOP_INDEXCOLIND).Value & "&type=2&search=h", _
        "", _
        SCRTIP & tblNoStop.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOSTOP_FIRSTNAMECOLIND).Text & " " & tblNoStop.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOSTOP_LASTNAMECOLIND) & ADAMASS)
Next

Set tblNoOffice = wsNoStop.ListObjects("NoOffice")
wsNoStop.Activate
DoEvents
'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:01:05"))

For RowCounter = 1 To tblNoOffice.ListRows.Count

    'Add link to the staff  details in the ADAM web application
    Set HLRange = tblNoOffice.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOOFFICE_INDEXCOLIND)
    Call AddHL(HLRange, _
        wsNoStop, _
        "https://adam.unctad.unctad.org/StaffDetails.aspx?id=" & tblNoOffice.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOOFFICE_INDEXCOLIND).Value & "&activemenu=1", _
        "", _
        SCRTIP & tblNoOffice.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOOFFICE_FIRSTNAMECOLIND).Text & " " & tblNoOffice.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOOFFICE_LASTNAMECOLIND) & ADAMWEB)
        DoEvents
    
    'Add link to the staff requests' list in the ADAM web application
    Set HLRange = tblNoOffice.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOOFFICE_ADACCEXPCOLIND)
    Call AddHL(HLRange, _
        wsNoStop, _
        "https://adam.unctad.unctad.org/RequestList.aspx?id=" & tblNoOffice.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOOFFICE_INDEXCOLIND).Value & "&activemenu=1", _
        "", _
        SCRTIP & tblNoOffice.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOOFFICE_FIRSTNAMECOLIND).Text & " " & tblNoOffice.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOOFFICE_LASTNAMECOLIND) & ADAMREQ)


    'Add link to the staff's equipment assignment history
    Set HLRange = tblNoOffice.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOOFFICE_FIRSTNAMECOLIND)
    Call AddHL(HLRange, _
        wsNoStop, _
        "https://adam.unctad.unctad.org/itinventory/EquipmentAssignment.aspx?id=" & tblNoOffice.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOOFFICE_INDEXCOLIND).Value & "&type=2&search=h", _
        "", _
        SCRTIP & tblNoOffice.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOOFFICE_FIRSTNAMECOLIND).Text & " " & tblNoOffice.DataBodyRange(RowCounter, NOOFFICE_LASTNAMECOLIND) & ADAMASS)
Next

Sub AddHL(HLRng As Range, Tgtws As Worksheet, tgtAddr As String, SubAddr As String, SCRTIP As String, Optional DispTxt As Variant)
'Colours list can be found at  http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

If IsMissing(DispTxt) Then
    
    Tgtws.Hyperlinks.Add _
    Anchor:=HLRng, _
    Address:=tgtAddr, _
    SubAddress:=SubAddr, _
    ScreenTip:=SCRTIP, _
    TextToDisplay:=HLRng.Text
Else
    Tgtws.Hyperlinks.Add _
    Anchor:=HLRng, _
    Address:=tgtAddr, _
    SubAddress:=SubAddr, _
    ScreenTip:=SCRTIP, _
    TextToDisplay:=DispTxt
End If
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error #" & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
         & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description, , "Error in subroutine AddHL (Module1)" & _
         "", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
End Sub


Style comment first - there is way too much repetition of identical boilerplate code. It ought to be in a parameterised subroutine. The crucial bit about how tbl.NoStop is selected is missing from the start of the code and may be crucial. My instinct is that there is a race condition if it works fine in the debugger but fails when run at full speed. My best guess is tha adding a few ms delay between the set HLRange and the AddHL might make all the difference. I have seen similar issues drawing a lot of graphs from VBA at once - some unlucky ones it tries to set the axis scale before the axes!

Here is how the two tables are selected at the beginning of the subroutine:
Set tblNoStop = wsNoStop.ListObjects("NoCloseAccount")
Set tblNoOffice = wsNoStop.ListObjects("NoOffice")
I repeated the set for table tblNoOffice before the second loop because I read somewhere on the web that this might solve the problem (but it doesn't).

I just tried to reverse the order of the loops, i.e. to run first the loop for table tblNoOffice and then the loop for tabl tblNoStop.  The result is the same: tblNoStop has the links, but tblNoOffice doesn't

Is this code also refreshing the two tables? If so, it's possibly continuing before the table is populated.

I think you will need to boil it down to a minimum reproducible example to allow us to test this on our local versions of Excel. Your code is still too complex and context dependent on magic names and ranges to be debugged by anyone else. Ideally just make one link that works OK and one that doesn't (though failure may depend on quantity).

Are your  query connections set to run as Background queries? If so, untick that option so the query finishes before passing control back to the VBA

@Rory: yes the tables are refreshed in the same subroutine.

@CHill60. Thank you for your suggestion. Actually the background flag was set to false only for the first table. Setting it to false for the second table as well solved the problem.

Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a specific question - which will come out of your best attempt to understand and locate a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the specific part of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely expect something), and don't understand why.

Thanks to the comment made by @CHill60, I added the line
ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - NoOffice").OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False

and the problem disappeared.
